Does mains pressure have any effect on toilet flush?
Does mains water pressure have any bearing on how well a toilet flushes, all else being equal?  E.g. jets are clean, there's no clog, flapper properly adjusted, vent clear, etc.   Would a toilet connected to mains of 80psi flush any differently than the same toilet connected to mains of 60psi?

Are you asking about a traditional residential tank toilet or something newer/fancier? Changes in line pressure would have some impact on the tank refill time, but nothing significant re: flushing.

Yes, a traditional tank toilet.  One of our toilets became finicky after I installed a pressure regulating valve in the basement, dropping the mains pressure from 80psi to 70 psi. Could it be that the fill valves let  more water in at higher pressures as the tank is emptying, contributing to the flush vortex?

Not impossible...

10 psi should not make much difference in the amount of water during the time the flush valve is open.

@mr blint, I think you answered your own question.

Is the toilet acting differently, or just a curious question?  Reducing the pressure from 80psi is good, since 80psi is close to the top of long term safe for pipe pressure.

@crip659  Toilet handle has to be held down for several extra seconds until the vortex forms, whereas it used to be much closer to a "hair trigger" situation. You could push the lever down and let go of it. Now, if you do that, water just fills the bowl.

It sounds more like two things changed at/near the same time.  changing the pressure valve and something changed in the toilet.  The fill valve has no relation to flushing action.  The toilet will flush just as well(if everything is good) with the shut off valve turned off and the tank full.

The toilet flushes from simple water head, not water pressure.  If you have a little more pressure, the tank will fill a bit faster, but it shouldn't flush any faster.
